# TFS Build publish folder (_PublishedWebsites) does not have dlls only referenced by sub libraries

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

After successful TFS build, the _PublishedWebsites in build drop folder does not have dlls referenced by libraries which is referenced by the main webproject.

It has only the libraries which were directly referenced from webproject.

Answer (score 2):

That's normal behavior. Reference all the necessary assemblies from your web application.

Comment: Due to few architecture constraints i could not add reference directly from main webproject, it should be only referenced from libraries which is referenced by webproject

Comment: If you can't reference them directly, you'll have to add a post-app-build step to copy them.

Comment: Actually i am not publishing from Visual Studio IDE, _Publishedwebsites folder is got from tfs build
Could you give me an example on how to give postbuild step from tfs build.